# Provided seeds do not result in a valid address only on mainnet

Tags: solana-program

This CPI call where I try to send tokens from a user token account to a PDA token account raises the following error:

```
Program failed to complete: Could not create program address with signer seeds: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address
```

This works fine on localnet btw, the error only happens on mainnet. Any reason why?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use invoke instead of invoke_signed. The error is not caught with local-test-validator for now.